# Packaging JVM with Application While Maintaining an Automated and Repeatable Build Process

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, build-automation

I'm currently working on a project that requires us to package a JRE with our application.  I'm normally against this as it makes keeping the JRE patched quite difficult, but in this case it is necessary.

- What are the best practices for packaging a JRE with an application
  as part of an automated build process?
- Where do you normally store the JRE files so that they can be picked
  up by your build process?  Shared file server?  What about making it
  an artifact in your maven repo?

Just trying to get a feel for what people do in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently do this for a desktop app I distribute.  I just have the JRE on the build server (which is really just some custom perl scripts and a web server.), in a folder, ant copies it to be part of the build tree which comes out of subversion, and then everything gets consumed by Nullsoft and builds the installer.  It's not great, but it works. I should also say, I at one time used to check it, and I'm happier with what I do now.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications keep jre in the root installation folder and the startup scripts would then use relative paths to use that jre. For e.g. Jprofiler

You can use [Maven repo for jre](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=com.sun&artifactId=jre-win32).

Comment: I'm not looking for where to put it as part of the build.  I'm wanting to know how people manage the JRE as an artifact of their build.

Comment: updated the maven repo for jre for windows, u can do for linux too